# Cannot map field of cascade list using Java stream()

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a `List<Country>` and it has `List<City>`. I want to retrieve `UUID` list of all cities in country list using Java stream(), but I cannot map them properly. Normally I could get `UUID` field of a list, but there is cascade list and I cannot find a proper solution for that. So, how can I solve the problem? Should I use `flatMap`?

```
List<UUID> cityUUIDList = countryList.stream().map(CityDTO::getUuid)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `countryList.stream().flatMap(c -> c.getCities().stream()).map(City::getUuid).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also get the List of `UUID` like this:

```
List<UUID> cityUUIDList = countryList.stream()
        .map(Country::getCities)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(CityDTO:::getUuid)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method, assuming you have something like:

```
class Country {
    List<CityDTO> cities = new ArrayList<>();
}

class CityDTO {
    UUID uuid;
    
    UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }
}

List<UUID> cityUUIDList = countryList.stream()
                                     .flatMap(c -> c.cities.stream())
                                     .map(CityDTO::getUuid)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```